# What is the purpose of trimming the bottom corners of TLC plates?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, chromatography

During my chemistry lab course, I was told by my instructor to make 2 small cuts on the bottom corners of the TLC (Thin-Layer Chromatography) plate. Does this make the solvent rise uniformly on the plate? Is this a standard practice in labs? I could not find any information online. In [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75887/diffusion-streaky-bands-on-tlc-plate) the OP has made the cuts as well, but this does not seem to make the solvent rise uniformly.

Comment: My guess is so you will remember which is the bottom of the plate. I cannot see how it would improve flow in any significant way.

Comment: Never heard of this. Certainly not std practice in any lab I've worked in.

Comment: Re: comments, It’s quite a personal thing. Plenty of people I know do it, plenty don’t.

Comment: @orthicresol I know plenty of people that don't operate correctly. This is totally another story. One can get decent results, nevertheless. I know lot of  people using ematocrito capillaries to deposite on the plate. It does not make it handbook practice, nor it should recommended. Of course preparing ad hoc capillaries is tedious and requires a higher than usual flame temperature, so many go with far too big capillaries. Etc.

Comment: @Alchimista What are ematocrito capillaries? Googling seems of no use. I use glass capillaries with a smaller diameter than melting point capillaries.

Comment: Something like melting point capillaries.  That was my meaning. A lot of groups use that (surprisingly! !!). Working approximately does not prevent results. .....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your question contains the answer. Think about capillarity.

Without the little cuts the eluant would be "sucked" and flow from both the bottom and the left ( and right) edges of the thin plate, resulting in a tilted flow that

- tends to move the elute faster along the vertical edges while clumping the spots to the center;
- decrease the resolution at the given conditions by deforming and enlarging the spots.

Think of it as a weird bad executed two dimensionally-developed plate, if it helps.

Note that beside resolution, the cuts should be there to guarantee a levelled horizontal and straight flow front, as requisite to obtain reliable and useful ratio front values.

(Good practice: draw the real appearance of the developed plate or even post it to the lab journal, so that a future user get a feeling of the separation whatever it happened. The latter not recommended if a product spots out to be irritant/allergenic).

[image: sketch of tlc plates handmade]

Left: correct - Right: not horizontal flow frontline due to capillarity at vertical edges.

As OP mentions an example with cutted corners but not levelled flow, obviously cutting the corners but plunging the plate in too much eluant is useless. The idea is to have eluant sucked up just by the bottom edge.

Comment: Well I've seen the light now! Never heard of this trick. Surprised it would matter. Is it considered standard practice?

Comment: It should be standard practice! Still, a not perfect plate might be of some help, of course. Sometimes you do the same over and over for instance.  But a Rf value shouldn't take into accoubt how far from center a compound/mixture was dropped.

Comment: @Night Writer ↑

Comment: Would help if TLC plates were sold like this. Cutting your own plates is a good way to have a reportable H&S incident.

Comment: Scissors marketing perhaps :) @Waylander. More seriously, normally TLC prepared plates come in a rather large size, or at least these are cheaper,  and then one cuts them in the meaningful size.

Comment: Here, when we use 4$\times$8 cm plates there is no need to cut the bottom. But when we cut the cheaper 20$\times$20 cm plates, the elution is much better with the cuts.

Comment: @alchimista I still have the scars on my fingers from cutting my own plates.

Comment: @Waylander. I have read that before chemists recognised themselves by scars. Apparently drilling corks was dangerous :) Source: Il sistema periodico by P. Levi. It should be translated in many languages. If not done, read it.I love it.

Comment: @Raoul Kessels. Genau, is mostly about geometry.

Comment: Well, I have always had the impression that when you cut the plate, the aluminium foil bends and silica gets detached from the foil. When put in the eluent, it goes up much faster in this gap then in the center. And since both sides are different, you get an horrible front

Comment: I known what you mean. It really goes to practical details.  Let us say that edge effects might be avoid. I would never use a ten cm foil for tre four deposited spots in routines such as reaction following or eluant selection.  Itt is quite some money for even a small but active group.  My answer points to the best practice. Same as I have commented with the calibre of capillaries. But yes the cheapest foils just suffices for individual assessment, either you cut them or use them as they are. Likely they are not very homogeneous in thickness/packing.

Comment: Can you cite some book or source which suggests trimming the plate? Also, I am using small plates with dimensions around 4 by 2 cm.

Comment: 4x2 might be even too short. Now, this really goes to practical details. Again read myt comments, everything is possible/acceptable. Whenever you gett a straight & levelled frontline is fine. They trick helps, especially with a little plate, getting that. No reference. You should see it yourself. Place a "empty" plate in the chamber 30'' or so, pencil mark the front. You should see something like in my sketch.